# Is it possible to output to and input from multiple audio devices simultaneously in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, asio

I'm running a feasibility study on a project I'm working on which would require me to output a signal on multiple different audio devices at once while simultaneously recording from multiple different inputs at once. I can't find confirmation of whether that's possible with winapi.

MacOS has aggregate devices which allow you to couple the channels of multiple audio devices together as channels of a single virtual device, but it would be preferable to offer an implementation in Windows.

Is there methodology through which I can tap multiple input devices at once, and output sound from multiple output devices at once on a windows machine?

I can work with any language or technology that would enable me to do so.

Comment: Of course it is possible, especially with a high-level API like DirectSound or XAudio, which handle the complexities of device interactions and mixing channels for you.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides classes for incoming and outgoing lines: `TargetDataLine`, `SourceDataLine`.

From the [Sound Trail / Playing Back Audio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html)

> If you're playing back multiple tracks of audio simultaneously, you probably want to have them all start and stop at exactly the same time. Some mixers facilitate this behavior with their synchronize method, which lets you apply operations such as open, close, start, and stop to a group of data lines using a single command, instead of having to control each line individually. Furthermore, the degree of accuracy with which operations are applied to the lines is controllable.

In addition to this, one has access to the individual bytes as they pass through the lines. It is possible to directly feed data buffer blocks to multiple lines from a single source. The accuracy will be regulated by the size of the buffer blocks. A 1000-byte block (if 4 bytes per frame) would theoretically have 1/1764 sec accuracy for an audio format with 44100 fps, 16-bit encoding, stereo.